# Can't get node app to run on openshift, Error: listen EACCES

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have been trying to fix this for hours, with endless googling, I try to start the app, go to the url and see a 503 Service Unavailable error, I then cd into app-root/repo, try to manually start server.js, and get the following:

```
[my-app-url.rhcloud.com repo]\> node server.js
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Connecting to server

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
at listen (net.js:1061:10)
at net.js:1143:9
at dns.js:72:18
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

This is driving me insane, all I'm trying to do is a simple api, and it works perfectly in my local environment.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the code where you set the port and address to listen to?

Comment: I thought I did, must have formatted the URL wrong http://pastebin.com/Z3D3NHAz

Answer (score 2):

Already another program or instance of this program is running on same port.

run - `sudo netstat -tapen | grep ":<<your given port>>"`

and then kill the process.

Then try to run the server...

Thanks

Comment: I got: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied

Comment: as it is in rhel may be you should install sudo and run the above - to install sudo - yum install sudo

Comment: Got: CRITICAL: yum.main: Error: rpmbdb open failed

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to the OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP, i see you are only binding to the correct port, not the ip also: https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-getting-started.html

https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-nodejs-http-and-websocket-example/blob/master/server.js#L1

```
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      response.write("Welcome to Node.js on OpenShift!\n\n");
      response.end("Thanks for visiting us! \n");
});

server.listen( port, ipaddress, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});

wss = new WebSocketServer({
    server: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  console.log("New connection");
  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    ws.send("Received: " + message);
  });
  ws.send('Welcome!');
});

console.log("Listening to " + ipaddress + ":" + port + "...");
```

Comment: replacing my server.js with that works fine, but it also ran fine before I started adding mongodb databases, my server.js is now this: http://pastebin.com/qWAUiaAq but the same errors persist

Comment: It's the exact same thing I posted in the original post, I thought maybe mongoose could be failing to connect, but it connects fine via node cli with the exact same parameters as the script, I'm going insane.

Comment: When you do your git push, do you get any errors about building/installing npm modules? Can you link to your package.json?

Comment: I get a few warnings about lack of readme data, package.json: http://pastebin.com/sf5gWSm3